# Почему не работает мой docker контейнер на heroku?(nest js + postgrse)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, heroku, развертывание

Всем привет. Пытаюсь развернуть свой сервер + бд на heroku. С докером работаю впервые, на heroku деплою второй раз) Поэтому, все что я делал - копировал со всяких видео без особого понимая происходящего. Я, вроде как, смог создать контейнер, который даже запускается и работает. Потом пытался задеплоить его на heroku. Для этого выполнил следующие команды: heroku container:push web --app cp-itr  |  heroku container:release web --app cp-itr. Попробовал сделать запрос - ошибка. Открываю логи, а там пишет, что не может подключится к бд. Проект, если что, на nest js + postgres. Приведу примеры моих докер файлов + .env . Надеюсь, этого хватит.

```
PORT=5000
POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_DB=cp_itr
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=112233
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=845439658659-unvuvrvv6vcoruij9nl3ia6ks6b6pu01.apps.googleusercontent.com
GOOGLE_SECRET=112233
GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI=https://cp-itr.herokuapp.com/web/auth/google/redirect
SECRET=SECRET3
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.13-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

COPY ./dist ./dist

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  main:
    container_name: main
    build:
      context: .
    env_file:
      - .development.env
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
      - 9229:9229
    command: npm run start:dev
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: always
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:13
    env_file:
      - .development.env
    environment:
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Comment: Хорошо. А не подскажите, что нужно исправить? Мне нужно как-то изменить образ приложения, чтобы в нем находилась и бд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По описанию выглядит так, что вы просто пытаетесь запустить образ вашего приложения без базы, т.к. локально вы её запускаете вместе с приложением в docker-compose, но удаленно на heroku грузите и запускаете только образ с приложением, поэтому оно и не может подключиться к базе.

У `heroku` есть возможность добавить `Postgres` базу данных к вашему приложению (у бесплатной базы есть ограничения, но для тестового приложения должно хватать). `Resource` -> `Add-ons` -> введите `Heroku Postgres`. После того как вы добавите базу в ваше приложение, вы сможете посмотреть настройки по которым к ней можно будет подключаться (они же появятся как `DATABASE_URL` в переменных окружения). Вам нужно будет сделать чтобы ваше приложение считывало эти настройки из env vars или просто захардкодить их, временно.

Comment: У меня, наконец, дошли руки попробовать то, о чем Вы написали. В общем, все сработало) Не так гладко, как хотелось бы, но все же. Спасибо, что подсказали, как нужно добавлять бд в самом heroku.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте не объединять все в один контейнер, а использовать контейнерную сеть, для этого нужно создать сеть:

```
docker network create resources
```

При этом мы не указываем драйвер сети, так как по умолчанию создаются сети с типом `bridge`, которые связывают изолированные контейнеры между собой.

Прописать к каждому контейнеру

```
networks:
  - resources
```

и изменить приложение, что бы обращение шло **не** на `localhost:5432`, а по на имя контейнера, к примеру:

> container_name: postgres

Обращаться нужно будет на адрес `postgres:5432` для этого отдельно пробрасывать порты не нужно.

---

Плюс данной системы связи приложение <-> БД в том, что не нужно для каждого проекта отдельно поднимать БД. Просто добавлять нужные базы.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Обязательно попробую, но чуть позже, когда не буду ограничен по времени) Сейчас, после стольких "танцев с бубнами", оно наконец заработало, и пусть работает пока)