# Django Channels + Nginx + Daphne в Docker

Tags: django, nginx, docker, django-channels

уже 2 дня пытаюсь решить проблему, испробовал множество вариантов, перечитал кучу статей и форумов, пока тупик. В своем Django приложении я подключил веб сокеты с помощью библиотеки Django Channels для реализации чата. Фронтенд на Vue js. Локально все работало хорошо, чатик моментально отображал сообщения, но как только я завернул все это дело в Docker, клиенская сторона перестала подключаться к веб сокетам. Мне кажется, либо я с настройками nginx что то сделал не так, либо в Docker. Я не devops и в этом не силен, поэтому прошу помощи!!

Dockerfile

```
###########
# BUILDER #
###########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.2 as builder

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYCECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get -y install postgresql gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# lint
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY . .

# install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/requirements.txt
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt


#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.2

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
RUN groupadd app
RUN useradd -m -g app app -p password
RUN usermod -aG app app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install netcat -y
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy entrypoint-prod.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh $APP_HOME

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app

# run entrypoint.prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
  echo "Waiting for postgres..."

  while ! nc -z $DB_HOST $DB_PORT;  do
    sleep 0.1
  done
      
  echo "Postgres started"
fi

exec "$@"
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: gunicorn school.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/media
    expose:
      - 8000
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    links:
      - redis
  db:
    image: postgres:10.1-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.db
  vue:
    build:
      context: ./scool-ui
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - vue_dist:/app/dist
    depends_on:
      - web
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
  daphne:
    image: daphne
    build: .
    working_dir: /home/app/web
    command: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 school.asgi:application
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
    links:
      - redis
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/media
      - vue_dist:/app/dist
    depends_on:
      - web
      - vue
      - daphne
    links:
      - daphne

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
  vue_dist:
  redis_data:
```

nginx/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.21.3-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream school {
    server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        root /app/dist;
        #index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://school;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /ws/ {
         proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8001;;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
         proxy_redirect off;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location /static/ {
    root /home/app/web;
    }

     location /media/ {
    root /home/app/web;
    }
}
```

Что пробовал:
Пытался запускать daphne из entrypoint.sh и пытался запустить daphne вместо gunicorn в web в docker-compose, в настройках nginx пробовал указывать 8000 порт

Так же на всякий случай скину метод конекта к сокету с клиенской стороны:

```
connect() {
  this.chatSocket = new WebSocket(
      'ws://127.0.0.1/ws/chat/' + String(this.id) + '/'
  );
  this.chatSocket.onopen = () => {
    this.status = "connected";
  };
  this.chatSocket.onmessage = ({data}) => {
    this.responseData.push(JSON.parse(data))
  }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1334971/341547 посмотрите, возможно данная схема применима для вас

Comment: а ссылку на репозиторий можете указать? чтобы можно было локально запустить

Comment: @Exploding Kitten напишите пожалуйста в телеграм, он указан в профиле, скину ссылку